# A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-share'

Tags: react-native

I try this commands for the installation of the library react-native-share

```
npm install react-native-share --save

react-native link react-native-share
```

But i got this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-share'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

Comment: Check this, it would help https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1490

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: 
I follow this guide of a similar problem with the maps plugin of react.[Link to guide](https://itnext.io/install-react-native-maps-with-gradle-3-on-android-44f91a70a395)

the following steps are the ones that work for me:

1_ `Modify android/build.gradle`

```
Add google() inside repositories

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // add google() here
        google()
```

2_ `Update com.android.tools.build.gradle to 3.1.0`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
      // update from 2.2.3 to 3.1.0 
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

3_ Add google() inside repositories after dependencies

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
    allprojects {
      repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        // add googgle() here
        google()
```

4_ `Add android.enableAapt2=false to android/gradle.properties`

```
android.enableAapt2=false // < ---  add here
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

5_ `Update gradle version in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
// from version 2.14.1
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
// change to 4.4
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

6_ `Run react-native run-android. (This might take a while since it’ll be downloading the updated gradle version).`